# The "helix" of NodeJs during "idle time"

Tags: node.js

I'm using NodeJs v0.10.29 and Express, among other things, for a project I'm working on.

The thing is that since I updated NodeJs to version 0.10.29 (from 0.10.28) a very annoyning thing is happening when I start the Express server up.

A very common issue was to look in the log generated by Express to see what was happening in case of error but now it's not possible without killing the server. Terminal scroll is locked (it can't go up...) because some kind of "helix" is spining round during "idle time" (| / - | \ | ....) at the end of the log.

Is it possible to avoid this without going back to 0.10.28?

Thanks

León

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about, and am running Node.js versions 0.10.26 through 0.10.29 and Express versions 3 and 4 on several applications.  Where are you seeing this, and what is generating your log?  Are you talking about the default application built by Express?  I'm not using that, so maybe that's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is not node doing this. It's probably one of the modules you are loading from npm, but probably not express either. You need to investigate with process of elimination to find what piece of code is doing that. Most likely the last time you ran "npm install", you got a newer version of some module and the new version does this but the old didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out who's the one: **npm** is *guilty* of this thing.

I used to type

```
$ npm start
```

which is defined as

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
}
```

If I use

```
$ nodemon app.js
```

log behaves as it used to.

**npm** added this "helix" at the end of the log. It can be seen when you use, for example:

```
$ npm install my-favourite-package
```

Version of **npm** is **1.4.14**